# QT Inverse Sawtooth with QCustomPlot

Tags: qt, plot

I need an Inverse Sawtooth plot for a stock management app I am making for university and I can´t make it work.

Currently:

```
void Widget_Resultados::CalculaValoresSierra(const Resultados &r){
  QVector<double> x;
  QVector<double> y;
  for (double iX = 0; iX < 100; iX += 0.1){
    x<<iX;
    y<<pow(-1,3.1416) * (sin(2*3.1416*iX*1/r.T)/iX)*2*r.Q/3.1416;
  }
  mSierra->setX(x);
  mSierra->setY(y);
}
```

Where r.T is the base of the triangle and r.Q is the side.
This is what it should look like [image]

Probably the function I am using is wrong, but I can´t find any other one.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what mSierra is in your code but I'm going to assume that it is the plot. In order to correctly plot your data you need to create a graph in you plot. Assuming you already added the plot to your layout [see here for setting up this in Qt](http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/tutorials/settingup) you can add a graph like this

```
mSierra->addGraph();
mSierra->graph(0)->setData(x, y);
// give the axes some labels:
mSierra->xAxis->setLabel("T [s]");
mSierra->yAxis->setLabel("Vp");
mSierra->->rescaleAxes();
mSierra->replot();
```

You can also take a look at this for more ways of customizing your plots.
http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/tutorials/basicplotting